# Elegant Way to Increase Price by Percentage with PHP

Tags: php

When I need to add a percentage to a price in order to increase it by a certain percentage I have this formula `$price * (1 + $percent / 100)` which is somewhat limiting.

For example if I wanted to increase the price by `200%` or `300%` I'd need to create a complex code to detect if its a 3 decimal number. And then extract the first number and replace the `1` like this `(2 + $percent / 100)`.

Is there a more elegant way to increase a price by a certain percentage?

Comment: Your formula would still work with 200% or 300% - no need to replace 1 with 2

Comment: Well so far `int`. But no reason why it couldn't be `float`. @Don'tPanic

Comment: Increasing by 200% percent is adding two times the price to it, which is `price * 3`, exactly as your formula does.

Comment: I agree with the others. It looks like it should work regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on every case

`$price = $price + ($percentage / 100 ) * $price`

But your formula is working with 200 or 300 without problem

Comment: How is this different than the formula posted in the question?

Comment: I would go as far as to say that this formula is actually more verbose than the op's one

Answer (score 2):

This is my way to do:

`$price = $price + ($price * $percent / 100)`

Works simple, calculate te percent of the price `($price * $percent / 100)` and then sums that to the initial price.